# Show that $-1$ is a square $\mod n$, if $n\equiv 1\mod 4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that $-1$ is a square modulo $n$ if, and only if $n\equiv 1\mod 4$.

One direction i think i have done...

So, we have that $n\equiv 1\mod 4$, from this follows that $n$ must be an odd number (if we have $n=4k+1$, where $4k$ is even).

In class, we have seen that $a$ is a quadratic residue if $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv 1\mod n$. In my case $\frac{n-1}{2}$ will be even and smaller than $n$. So, $(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv 1\mod n$. Is this idea correct?

I am stuck with the other direction of the proof... Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: You probably proved it is a QR **if and only if** $\dots$. Then you can use the same proof, if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$, then your power is congruent to $-1$.

Comment: So $-1$ is a square modulo $9$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, not only, $5$ works too...
I have to show in general that if $-1$ is a square modulo $n$, then $n\equiv 1\, mod \, 4$.

Comment: @Lullaby So what do you have to prove? Title (now) says "if $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ then $-1$ is a square". Your comment says "If $-1$ is a square then $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$", question body says "if and only if". For two of the three variants my comment still applies: Can you find a number $x\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ such that $x^2+1$ is a multiple of $9$?